# bookmarklet location.href on about:blank

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've created a bookmarklet as follows:

```
// Assuming a keyword of 'pin',
//   'pin' will retrieve all bookmarks
//   'pin linux' will retrieve all bookmarks tagged 'linux'
//   'pin linux tools' will retrieve all bookmarks tagged both 'linux' and 'tools'
javascript:params='%s';url='http://pinboard.in/u:xiong.chiamiov';if(params!=''){tags=params.split('%20');for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++){url+='/t:'+tags[i];}}location.href=url;
```

This works as intended on existing pages.  However, when a page doesn't actually exist in the current tab (for instance, about:blank), I get nothing, presumably because `document.location` doesn't yet exist.  `open(url)` does not work, either.

Is there another way to make this work?  I'm using Firefox, if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

You code works on my Firefox - page redirect from about:blank to your webpage(http://pinboard.in/u:xiong.chiamiov/t:%s).

I test document.location from a about:blank page, it works too, please try:

1. Open a about:blank page in Firefox
2. run javascript:alert(document.location.href);void(0)

*i think you'd better add void(0) at the end on your code.